# PHP do no insert duplicates in database from for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, import, duplicates

I've looked through some similar questions but couldn't find a solution. So I am importing data from excel table. Data contains company name, company unique number, city and address.

What I need is, to check if unique number exists in database, and if yes - skip, if no - create record. Below is my code, that is looping through the rows:

```
for ($i = $data_start_row; $i < $sheetCount + 1; $i++) {
    $externalsales->eik = $spreadSheetAry[$i][$client_eik];
    if ($externalsales->getSocieteByBulstat() > 0) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $importfromexcel->nom = $spreadSheetAry[$i][$client_name];
        $importfromexcel->address = $spreadSheetAry[$i][$client_address];
        $importfromexcel->town = $spreadSheetAry[$i][$client_city];
        $importfromexcel->tva_intra = $spreadSheetAry[$i][$client_eik];
        $importfromexcel->userId = $user->id;
        $importfromexcel->insertSocieteRecord();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that there are sometimes more than one row in the file, with same data for missing records, so duplicates are created in database. How can I avoid this?

Tried with `goto start;` where `start:` is before for loop but this doesn't work (bunch of records for the first missing records are inserted like +500 duplicates).

Setting one of the column as unique is my last option, but I prefer to do it in script.

Comment: Use `INSERT IGNORE` to skip the insert if there's a duplicate key.

Comment: You should make the key a unique index so you can't get duplicates.

Comment: @barmar `INSERT IGNORE INTO` also insert all records i.e. duplicates. As for the unique index, this is my last option.

Comment: Of course it does. The only way it knows what to ignore is if there's a unique constraint.

Comment: Anyway, just check whether the column you want to be unique is already in the database before you call `insertSocieteRecord()`.

Comment: @bramar So, besides the unique column, there is no other way to avoid duplicates in this case, right?

Comment: A duplicate _key_ is not the same as a duplicate _column_. You can have a _key_ constraining multiple columns.

Comment: @milenmk As I said, you can check for the duplicate in your script before inserting.

Comment: Unique indexes are the ultimate solution implemented in relational databases to prevent duplicate values occurring in a column or combination of columns. You can develop code that does duplicate value checking, but 1) you have to implement the duplicate check for every route that inserts or updates data for that particular field 2) in case of concurrent inserts, there is a possibility that two processes try to insert / update the same value at the same time, thus passing the duplicate check, yet ending up with duplicate values. It is so much easier to create a unique index...

Comment: @bramar For some reason I cannot add unique key. This is the query `ALTER TABLE societe ADD UNIQUE idx_societe_tva_intra (tva_intra);` and this is the result: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'tva_intra'` when I'm 100% sure thereis not such a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for anyone who stumbles upon here, the final solutions for me is as follows:

Due to some limitations of the database, I was not able to set a unique index for the filed `tva_intra` in the target table `societe` so I switched to 2 steps processing

**1st step:** I have created custom table `societe_temp`, with same fields as described in the question, and for this table I was able to set a unique index for field `tva_intra`:

```
`ALTER TABLE societe_temp ADD UNIQUE idx_societe_temp_tva_intra (tva_intra);`
```

Then insert the records from the excel file in this table thus avoiding any duplicate records.

**2nd step** Get the records from the temp table `societe_temp` and insert them in the master table 'societe'

I know this is not the most optimal solution, but it is a workaround that can help someone someday.